# Remove the last character of an array

Tags: powershell, scripting

i'm trying to remove the last character of an array.

I have an array with:

name1;

name2;

Now i want to remove the last ";".

I'v though on something like:

```
$array = $array | Select -last 1 | foreach{$_.replace(";", "")}
```

But thats just an idea. Also not working, because it will leave only the last entry.

Comment: Do you want all the `;` to be removed or just the `;` of the last element?

Comment: only the last one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change just the last object, process every object of the array and check if it's the last. `replace` only on the last one:

```
$array = $array | ForEach-Object { 
    if( $array.IndexOf($_) -eq ($array.count -1) ){
        $_.replace(";","")
    }else{$_}  
}
```

Comment: you can use regex instead of matching the length and index of character. This makes lengthy operation for small task.

Comment: @NirajGajjar : It's not matching the index of the character but the index of the last item in the array.

Comment: @NirajGajjar I don't do that. `$array.IndexOf($_) -eq ($array.count -1)` checks if `$_` is the last item of `$array`. If so `$_.replace(";","")` replaces all the `;` in the string. But I am very curious how you would match a whole array with a regex. pls show me! (no irony or sarcasm I realy would like to learn that)

Comment: I have already given the short answer for the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to remove/replace last semi colon ';' from each element.

```
$array | foreach{ $_ -replace ';$', '' }
```

and if you want to remove the same from `any where in the string`, just remove the `$`